# Using Pandas to get 1 Minute Average of TmeSeries CSV Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below CSV file

> DateTIme,172.25.150.88,172.25.150.12,172.25.150.105,172.25.150.43,172.25.150.47,172.25.150.95
>
> 2018-11-0202:49:42,54457,51776,43164,52074,48227,52165
>
> 2018-11-0202:49:43,48728,48516,47605,48202,48077,48304
>
> 2018-11-0202:49:44,47879,48699,48243,48153,48483,48364

Using pandas I import the file and set the datetime index:

```
data = pd.read_csv("throughput_88_12_105_43_47_95.csv")
data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DateTIme'],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')
```

Now data dataframe looks like below:

> DateTIme  172.25.150.88  172.25.150.12  172.25.150.105  172.25.150.43  172.25.150.47  172.25.150.95            datetime
>   0       2018-11-0202:49:42          54457          51776           43164          52074          48227          52165 2018-11-02 02:49:42
>
> 1       2018-11-0202:49:43          48728          48516           47605          48202          48077          48304 2018-11-02 02:49:43
>
> 2       2018-11-0202:49:44          47879          48699           48243          48153          48483          48364 2018-11-02 02:49:44
>
> 3       2018-11-0202:49:45          48009          48751           47813          48359          48581          48793 2018-11-02 02:49:45
>
> 4       2018-11-0202:49:46          48905          48650           47578          48285          48055          48761 2018-11-02 02:49:46

To do 1 minute average accross all columns:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['172.25.150.88','172.25.150.12','172.25.150.105','172.25.150.43','172.25.150.47','172.25.150.95'],index=data['datetime'])


 df.resample('1Min').mean()
```

This gives me:

> 172.25.150.88  172.25.150.12  172.25.150.105  172.25.150.43  172.25.150.47  172.25.150.95
>   datetime
>   2018-11-02 02:49:00            NaN            NaN             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
>
> 2018-11-02 02:50:00            NaN            NaN             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN
>
> 2018-11-02 02:51:00            NaN            NaN             NaN            NaN            NaN            NaN

How can I get the 1-minute average? All I am getting is NAN.

Comment: check your datatypes, maybe they didn't read in as numbers correctly.  `print df.dtypes` should give `float64` or `int64` for numeric columns.  anything else indicates problems in your dataset

Comment: >>> df.dtypes
172.25.150.88     float64
172.25.150.12     float64
172.25.150.105    float64
172.25.150.43     float64
172.25.150.47     float64
172.25.150.95     float64
dtype: object

Comment: Given that you are working with datetimeindex, you need to use df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')

Comment: Did that 
>>> df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index,format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')

But >>> df.resample('1Min').mean() still gives me all NaNs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:

```
In [1702]: df
Out[1702]: 
             DateTIme  172.25.150.88  172.25.150.12  172.25.150.105  172.25.150.43  172.25.150.47  172.25.150.95
0  2018-11-0202:49:42          54457          51776           43164          52074          48227          52165
1  2018-11-0202:49:43          48728          48516           47605          48202          48077          48304
2  2018-11-0202:49:44          47879          48699           48243          48153          48483          48364

In [1703]: df.DateTIme=pd.to_datetime(df.DateTIme,format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S') 
In [1707]: df.resample(rule='1Min', on='DateTIme').mean()
Out[1707]: 
                     172.25.150.88  172.25.150.12  172.25.150.105  172.25.150.43  172.25.150.47  172.25.150.95
DateTIme                                                                                                      
2018-11-02 02:49:00   50354.666667   49663.666667    46337.333333   49476.333333   48262.333333        49611.0
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I used exactly the dataframe provided by you in the post. It works for me fine. Please check.